# How to display ONE specific WP Post (ID pulled) from a specific Category

Tags: php, wordpress, post

There are a lot of various explanations and guides when it comes to how to show ALL posts from a specific category in WP.

But I want to show just 1 (one) specific post (ID) from a specific WP category on the page.

Using `query_posts( 'p=31213' );` doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) if you want to get data for a single post.

Get post with ID 7

```
$post_7 = get_post( 7 ); 
$title = $post_7->post_title;
echo $title;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($post_7);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Nothing happens, I've tried. Do you mind to post a complete code block please?

Comment: Do you have a post with ID 7? Maybe get the ID from an actual post and try it.

Comment: See the new code. You need to print out results to the screen using echo or print_r.